# Unnecessary Indentations in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a webpage:[image: Webpage (on left) and HTML source code (on right)]However, I want to only focus on text within the div tag labelled "class='body conbody'". I want my program to look inside of this tag and output the text exactly like how they appear on the webpage.

Here is my code so far:

```
pres_file = directory + "\\" + pres_number + ".html"
    with open(pres_file) as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'html.parser')
    desiredText = soup.find('div', class_='body conbody')    
    for para in desiredText.find_all('p'):
        print(para.get_text())
```

The problem with my current code is that whenever I try to print the paragraphs, (a), (1), (2), (b), and (c) are always formatted with a lot of unnecessary newlines and additional spaces after it. [image: My current output] However, I would like for it to output text that is equivalent to how it looks on the webpage. How can I change my code to accomplish this?

Comment: The screenshot you presented does not show the web page's sources code that Beautiful Soup operates on. It shows the browser's DOM after the HTML was parsed and interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

> I want my program to look inside of this tag and output the text exactly like how they appear on the webpage.

The browser does a lot of processing to display a web page. This includes removing extra spaces. Additionally, the browser developer tools show a parsed version of the HTML as well as potential additions from dynamic JavaScript code.

On the other hand, you are opening a raw text file and get the text as it is, including any formatting such as indentation and line breaks. You will need to process this yourself to format it the way you want when you output it.

There are at least two things to look for:

1. Is the indentation tab or space characters? By default `print()` represents a tab as 8 spaces. You can either replace the tabs with spaces to reduce the indentation or you can use another output method that allows you to configure specify how to show tabs.
2. The strings themselves will include a newline character. But then `print()` also adds a line break. So either remove the newline character from each string or do `print(para.get_text(), end='')` to disable print adding another newline.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strip()` on strings, like `para.get_text().strip()`. This will remove any whitespaces before and after the string.

You can use either `lstrip()` and `rstrip()` to remove only the exceeding whitespaces from the left or right side of the string.

```py
s = "          \t \n\n something  \t  \n          "
print(s.strip())  # 'something'
print(s.lstrip()) # 'something  \t  \n          '
print(s.rstrip()) # '          \t \n\n something'
```

Comment: at least explain what that does

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

1. Strip left and right of the p
2. Indent the paragraph with 1em (so 1 times the font size)
3. Newline each paragraph

```
font_size = 16 # get the font size
for para in desiredText.find_all('p'):
    print(font_size * " " + para.get_text().strip(' \t\n\r') + "\n")
```